# User feed and Question feed

Tags: support, user-interface, notifications

Do we have **User feed** and **Question feed** by **emails notification**?

If we do not, can we promote to have these features?

PS. It is **NOT** asking about off-site service. What I wonder is whether there is an email notification service for **a specific User** feed or **a specific question** feed provided by Phys SE. There is this service for question Tags on a particular category. But NOT for **a specific User** feed or **a specific question** feed. Why **NOT**? Thanks.

Comment: Feedly is an option. There is a whole list of alternatives [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0ApTo6f5Yj1iJdFRfWmhUVjV0WkktTjJhUUE4dGR5WUE&type=view&gid=0&f=true&sortcolid=-1&sortasc=true&rowsperpage=250)

Comment: Chrome/Chromium and Opera web browsers *natively* support RSS feeds. I assume Firefox does as well, but cannot confirm this.

Comment: but when I press the "question feed" or "user feed" button in the Chrome browser, I only see (1) the Feeder or (2) Google Reader. The (2) does not work. Are you sure that we can use Email or Feedly to do question feed or user feed???

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand my question??? I do have the Feedly (which can do for the arXiv). But I am saying using Feedly or email notification for a specific SE question? Does that work?

Comment: The user feed and question feed are Atom feeds. You can use them with _any_ modern RSS reader, including Feedly. If your browser only shows Feeder and Google Reader, that means it's configured to only show those two, but that doesn't mean those are the only options supported.

Comment: @Idear Copy the feed URL and subscribe to it with feedly

Comment: thanks. I am 100% idiot. But how about email notification? Use Feedly for sending email notification?

Comment: @Manishearth: How exactly is this off-topic?

Comment: @dimension it's asking for help with off-site services and product recommendations.

Comment: @Manishearth: No, it is not asking off-site service. I wonder whether there is email notification for a specific User feed or specific question provided by Phys SE. What I found out is, so far, "NO".I think you misunderstand really... Perhaps I express in the wrong way.

Comment: Do you mean this sort of a feed: http://physics.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/ENTER-USER-ID-HERE ?

Comment: @Dimensio1n0: Yes, exactly. Does that work for email or Feedly?

Comment: @Idear: I don't know, you could set up a chat room, and add thhe wanted feed to it, and monitor the chat room daily.

Comment: I've tested it here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12114/userfeedtest May take a while before it works

Comment: @idear it was, now it is ok